# PHP headers expiration check

Tags: php, caching, header, http-headers

I create a custom application, and I like to pass some PHP variables into CSS.

The approach I use, is a style.php file that serving CSS headers, so the HTTP request it addresses the request as a normal CSS file.

The problem with this approach is that on every request, I have to load some large PHP files in memory.

What I like to do is to check the expiration date of the file and if the file is no yet expired then do not run the script, and instead to send a cached file.

So, is there any solution for that problem ?

My php file I like to looks like something like that:

```
<?php
    // Enter here several headers to cache the file and other operations
    // Check here if the file must be re-executed or load a cached version instead
    // Enter here the inclution of my application scripts with include_once(....)
?>
body
{
    background-color: <?php echo $options->css['bg_color']; ?>
}
```

Kind regards
Merianos Nikos

Comment: How often do you CSSs change? Usually its easier to recreate the stylesheets the moment you deploy your application, because between the deployments they don't change anyway.

Comment: Check the expiration date of what file exactly? How do you expect the expiration date to be maintained?

Comment: I don't mean the expiration time of the file. The php file that will serve the CSS will have headers(....) for expiration, and I like to check that headers expiration.

Comment: I am sorry too, I am really not sure as to what you mean. It sounds like you're asking for the server to decide if it should generate the CSS based on a header, but the server is what sets the header. It doesn't know what headers it has sent in the past. You can actually just set the headers expiry date and then your clients browsers shouldn't request the CSS file aka. your PHP script until it has expired (or they clear their browser cache). Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that is correct :( xaxaxa :D I am sorry that I can't describe my problem better, but in way I think this is what I mean. Thanks a lot @deed02392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar to what you are doing and solved the problem parsing the CSS files server side. Here is a [link](https://github.com/nicoladj77/Css-Helper) to a simple class that does just that (it's what i use right now). Basically it parses all the files in a directory and uses strtr() to replace values in the css file

```
class Css {
    //this is an associative array that's used when replacing
    private $settings;
    //This is the path (relative to this file) to the dir that holds the css files to parse
    private $cssDir = "css/";
    //private varray to store the files
    private $cssFiles = array();
    //This is the path (relative to this file) to the dir where the parsed css files wil be written
    private $outCssDir = "../css/";

    /**
     * the class thake only one parameters, an associative array of keys to replace with their respective values
     */
    function __construct($settings) {
        $this -> settings = $settings;
        $this -> readFiles();
        $this -> replaceValuesInCssStrings();

    }

    private function readFiles() {
        $dir = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this -> cssDir;
        if (file_exists($dir)) {
            if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
                /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
                while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                    //filter out .. and .
                    if ($entry !== "." && $entry !== "..") {
                        $cssFiles[$entry] = file_get_contents($dir . $entry);
                    }
                }

                closedir($handle);
            }
        }
        $this -> cssFiles = $cssFiles;

    }

    private function replaceValuesInCssStrings() {
        foreach ($this->cssFiles as $fileName => $fileContent) {
            $this->cssFiles[$fileName] = strtr($fileContent, $this-> settings);

        }
    }
    /**
     * renders the parsed css files in a <style> tag
     */
    public function render() {
        $css = "<style>\n";
        foreach ($this -> cssFiles as $fileContent) {
            $css .= $fileContent;
        }
        $css .= "</style>";
        echo($css);
    }

    /**
     * writes the parsed css files to the $outCssDir (keeping their names intact)
     */
    public function renderToFile() {
        $dir = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this -> outCssDir;
        if (file_exists($dir)) {
            foreach($this->cssFiles as $fileName => $fileContent){
                file_put_contents($dir . $fileName, $fileContent);

            }   
        }
    }
    /**
     *  this is just in case you want to call echo ($css)
     */
    public function __toString() {
        $this -> render();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a very nice approach and I already have use it in another web application I made.

The one I create now, I need to write the CSS into the php file with imediatly value in place.

I change my code above to show you what I mean. Anyway, thank you for your code !! :)